# Fetching number from string in php

Tags: php

```
$string = '763:74
74:274
177:474';

$number = array('763', '74', '177');
```

I need to get the corresponding values of `$number` from `$string`. Example: if `number = 763` I need `string value 74`. If `number = 74` I need `string value 274` and so on.

What right now what I'm doing is *exploding* `$string` at `:` character, looping and matching.

Looking for some better solution.

Comment: *Right now what i am doing is exploding $string at :, looping and matching.* Show the code. I bet you're really close to the solution!

Comment: @Rizier123 Solution I have achieved but I want to avoid loop. It slows down the whole process if $string data increases.

Comment: You can create an array, where the number before the colon is the key and the number after the colon the value. So then you can just do: `echo $lookupArray[$yourNumber];`

Comment: $string data is coming from another source.

Comment: add the code which you have tried...

Comment: https://3v4l.org/F5t2P As an example

Comment: @Rizier123 awesome solution!! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First I split the string with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and use a new line as delimiter (`\n`), where I also consume all spaces (`\s*`) on the right and left side, so you don't have them in the key:

```
preg_split("/\s*\n\s*/", $string)
```

Then I go through each pair of numbers (`x:y`) with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it by a colon. So you end up with an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 763
            [1] => 74
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 74
            [1] => 274
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 177
            [1] => 474
        )

)
```

At the end I use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to say, that you want to use the 0st column as key and the 1st column as value.

Code:

```
<?php

    $string = '763:74
    74:274
    177:474';

    $result = array_column(
        array_map(function($v){
            return explode(":", $v);
        }, preg_split("/\s*\n\s*/", $string)
    ), 1, 0);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [763] => 74
    [74] => 274
    [177] => 474
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert your string into an array simply using `preg_replace_callback` like as

```
$string = '763:74
74:274
177:474';

$result = [];
preg_replace_callback('/(\d+):(\d+)/m',function($m)use(&$result){
    $result[$m[1]] = $m[2];
},$string);

print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [763] => 74
    [74] => 274
    [177] => 474
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/473200)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `preg_match` - first you find the position of the key string, then you find the pair with that key to know the length of the pair.:

```
function find_in_string($n,$string){
    preg_match("/(^|\s+)($n)(?=:)/",$string,$m1,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    preg_match("/(^|\s+)($n\:\d+)/",$string,$m2);
    return substr($string,$m1[2][1]+ strlen($n)+1,strlen($m2[2])-strlen($n));
}
```

Example:

```
$string = '763:74
74:274
177:474';
foreach(array('763', '74', '177') as $n){
    echo find_in_string($n,$string);
}
```

Output:

```
74
274
474
```

Demo:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/320e8ba1b47e62b75459aaf70f07994fe531b101